# how to get full name to blob

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-storage

**How do we get the path to a specific blob without the container name?**

You can list blobs like so:

```
            var query = await @in.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(string.Empty, true, BlobListingDetails.None, int.MaxValue, null, null, null);
            var blobs = query.Results.OfType<CloudBlockBlob>()
                .OrderByDescending(m => m.Properties.LastModified)
                .Take(msg.Quantity)
                .ToList();
```

You can then iterate each one:

```
            foreach (var blob in blobs)
            {
                var filepath = string.Join("/", blob.Uri.LocalPath.Split('/').Skip(2));
                //dostuff

            }
```

Instead of having to do this ugly `string.Join("/", blob.Uri.LocalPath.Split('/').Skip(2))` join/split, can we get the path (**minus the container name**) in a simpler way such as blob.Path() or something?

**Example:** storageAccount\myContainer\some\path\file.jpg

**Expected Result**: `\some\path\file.jpg`

Comment: I suppose `blob.Name` is exactly what you need?

Answer (score 2):

You can just do `blob.Name` to get the full path of the blob.

```
 foreach (var blob in blobs)
    {
       var filepath = blob.Name;
    }
```

Example:

My output was this `New Directory/test.svg`